# Длина Border

Tags: css3, css, xhtml, html

Здравствуйте.

Есть блок div123 /div c определёнными размерами. Ему присвоена `border-bottom:1px solid #000;`.

Как сделать длину этого border не на весь блок, а, скажем, на 30% или ...px c позиционированием в центре низа блока div, чтобы border-bottom начинался с центра и распределялся на 30%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что именно сделать хотите, но, может, это поможет -
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ydfna47/).

Параметр box-shadow: 0px **B** 0px **A** #000;

**A** = Сколько хотите отнять слева и справа пикселей.

**B** = + **A** + высота рамки в пикселях.

35px и -30px разница, высота рамки = 5px.

Comment: Или такой костыль =)) http://jsfiddle.net/vy0pgk28/1/

Comment: Этот костыль лучше моего)

Comment: Скажите, а как дать отступ, чтобы не прилипал к DIV?

Comment: Спасибо! понял! добавил просто top:)